# The contents of the input file are always undefined when I print formData, why? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I'm trying to upload a file (may be multiple as well) but after uploading to the input component, the only thing I saw after appended to *FormData()* is *undefined*. But, if I print an object *info* or *info['data']*, it will appear.

```js
fileHandler =(input) => {

    const formData = new FormData();
    const info = this.createDataBlob();

    for (let i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {

      formData.append(input.files[i].name,input.files[i])
      info['data'].push(this.createFileHeader(input.files[i].name))

    }

    formData.append('content.json',info)
    console.log( 'Processed Data:', formData['content.json'])
}

//used as content info for the API endpoint - saves all file dicts
createDataBlob = () => ({'data':[] , 'storage': 'neo4j-driver' })

 //returns a dict used to describe the file
createFileHeader = (name, description='') => ({ 'name': name, 'text': description})


render(){
  return (
    <Form>
      <input
        label="Custom file input"
        accept=".shp, .csv"
        type="file"
        id="input"
        multiple
        onChange={ (event) => this.fileHandler(event.target)}
      />
    </Form>
  );

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not `console.log` `FormData` entries this way, this is a special object.

Quote from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) website:

> The FormData object lets you compile a set of key/value pairs to send using XMLHttpRequest. It is primarily intended for use in sending form data, but can be used independently from forms in order to transmit keyed data.

However, if you would like to log out these values, you could use `entries()` to access them this way.

```js
const fileHandler = (event) => {
        const formData = new FormData();

        for (let i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
            formData.append(event.target.files[i].name, event.target.files[i].type);
        }

        // use values this way (entries)
        for (var key of formData.entries()) {
            console.log(`${key[0]}, ${key[1]}`);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                label="Custom file input"
                accept=".shp, .csv"
                type="file"
                id="input"
                multiple
                onChange={fileHandler}
            />
        </div>
    );
```

Also, I made a little change for your `onChange` in this example, using target in the handler, but your method was also fine I think.